# Very simple python data entry

Tags: python, keyboard

I have no training in python.  I know QBasic (yes I am 73!) but I have a hard time grasping OOP, and classes. I still think with QBasic ideas.
I want to make a simple prog to enter alphanumeric data using keyboard mainly, then process it into a txt file. I want to use it as stand alone outside python. I can understand a bit of canvas, keyboard etc. but cannot put them together to make a "box on the screen that tells what to do and sends stuff into the processing algorithm".  I just can't see the big picture.  Does anyone have some simple examples that I might understand and use? The processing of data I can do.
Jon

Answer (score 0):

```
#when this is ran it will ask What would you like to input and whatever you type will be set as the variable input 
input = input("What would you like to input")
#this creates a txt file
file = open("textfilename.txt", "w") 
#this will get the variable input and write it in the text file
file.write('input') 
#this closes the txt file
file.close()
```

Comment: Thank you Caio.  But where do I type it?  Jon

Comment: You need a program that reads python like Intelijj  
here's a youtube video explaining how to install python in IntelliJ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=euotGsQq8Bk

Answer (score -1):

I used to program BASIC too. Python is very similar. I don't see why you would have to worry about an object-oriented approach especially if you're just doing simple data entry. This concise doc is very useful for former BASIC programmers to cut through the BS and show you the BASICS of python by showing how to do functions you already know. It's pretty much the same big picture if your just doing basic stuff:

rox.sourceforge.net/desktop/book/export/html/44.html